# Can we set the size in tmpfs syntax as percentage instead of static size

Tags: linux, rhel, fstab, tmpfs

Can we set the size in the following syntax as percentage instead of static size?

example from `/etc/fstab`

```
tmpfs  /var/work   tmpfs   size=100g   0 0
```

lets say we have ram memory with `120g` , we can set the size to used `100g` from the ram as mentioned above

but is it possible to set for example `80%` in size instead of static value - is it possible?

example

```
`tmpfs  /var/work   tmpfs   size=80%   0 0`   ?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the kernel docs for tmpfs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/tmpfs.txt):

```
tmpfs has three mount options for sizing:

size:      The limit of allocated bytes for this tmpfs instance. The 
           default is half of your physical RAM without swap. If you
           oversize your tmpfs instances the machine will deadlock
           since the OOM handler will not be able to free that memory.
nr_blocks: The same as size, but in blocks of PAGE_SIZE.
nr_inodes: The maximum number of inodes for this instance. The default
           is half of the number of your physical RAM pages, or (on a
           machine with highmem) the number of lowmem RAM pages,
           whichever is the lower.

These parameters accept a suffix k, m or g for kilo, mega and giga and
can be changed on remount.  The size parameter also accepts a suffix %
to limit this tmpfs instance to that percentage of your physical RAM:
the default, when neither size nor nr_blocks is specified, is size=50%
```

Comment: so we can for example to define size=90% , in that case is it mean it will used 90% of RAM and each 1% that higher from 90% is used the disk ?

Comment: No. You can define `size=90%`, then the total size of that tmpfs mount will be 90% of the size your RAM. There is no usage of disk.

Comment: so what happens if I set size=90% , and tmpfs used all 90% and more ?

Comment: from my understanding when tmpfs reached 90% , then any >90% will used the swap

Comment: Not sure where you got that understanding from. Here's an example: RAM 20GB, swap 10GB, and a tmpfs mount on `/foo` with `size=90%`. Then you can only put 90% of 20GB = 18GB worth of data in `/foo`. You can't put any more, because that is the limit. It doesn't matter how much swap you have.

Comment: I am very confuse because what you wrote is about ramdisk and not tmpfs

Comment: so in that case what is the diff between ramdisk to tmpfs if they do exactly

Comment: These two differences between ramfs and tmpfs make tmpfs much more manageable however this is one major drawback; tmpfs may use SWAP space. If your system runs out of physical RAM, files in your tmpfs partitions may be written to disk based SWAP partitions and will have to be read from disk when the file is next accessed. In some environments this can be seen as a benefit as you are less likely to get out of memory exceptions as you could with ramfs because more ‘memory’ is available to use.*

Comment: Which doesn't contradict any of what I said. Where does the quoted text say you can put more data in a tmpfs mount than is specified by the size parameter?

Comment: so as I understand also ramdisk do the same , lets say we configured ramdisk with 90G when memory is 100G , then what is the diff between ramdisk to tmpfs?

Comment: @yael the place to ask questions is over here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask